# <th> tag does not follow with the data loop

Tags: html, vue.js

I am new to vue and currently working on a project that will load data from database and display it in a table. There are 9 table headers under  tag and under the  will have the v-for loop that will load the data from database (please refer to the code below). However, the data was successfully loaded but it does not load to the next column that follows the table header (please refer to the image below). Any suggestion on what to do for this? Thank you.

P.S. I have tried to do some research but none provide me the answer that I am looking for as I did 3 layers of nested v-for loop.

This is how the data being loaded, but everything is put under the "agency" column
[image: This is how the data being loaded, but everything is put under the "agency" column]

These are the respective columns that these data should be appended into but it is empty due to the misconfiguration
[image: these are the respective columns that these data should be appended into but it is empty due to the misconfiguration]

```html
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">
      Agency
    </th>
    <th>
      Ref No
    </th>
    <th>
      Document Type
    </th>
    <th>
      Category
    </th>
    <th>
      Description
    </th>
    <th>
      Submission
    </th>
    <th>
      Starting Date
    </th>
    <th>
      Closing Date
    </th>
    <th>
      Action
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <div v-for="values in objects">
        <div v-for="value in values">
            <tr v-for="item in value">
                <td scope="col"> {{ item.agency }} </td>
                <td scope="col"> {{ item.reference }} </td>
                <td scope="col"> {{ item.type }} </td>
                <td scope="col"> {{ item.category }} </td>
                <td scope="col"> {{ item.description }} </td>
                <td scope="col"> {{ item.submission }} </td>
                <td scope="col"> {{ item.starting_date }} </td>
                <td scope="col"> {{ item.closing_date }} </td>
                <td scope="col">
                    <a :href="item.link" target="_blank"> View </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </div>
</tbody>
```

Comment: If you have 3 levels of array, you could try to flatten them with `array.flat()`, which will level all the elements of the array to root level so you can do a single loop. I tested it in a mock I made with the code you displayed and it worked. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `div`s as the root element of the `tbody`. As they are rendered in the DOM, it takes out the `td`'s space and the first loop ends up in the first column.

You can solve this by replacing `div` with `template`, since it does not render on final DOM output.

Here is a fix:

```
<tbody>
    <template v-for="values in objects">
        <template v-for="value in values">
            <tr v-for="item in value">
                <td scope="col"> {{ item.agency }} </td>
                <td scope="col"> {{ item.reference }} </td>
                <td scope="col"> {{ item.type }} </td>
                <td scope="col"> {{ item.category }} </td>
                <td scope="col"> {{ item.description }} </td>
                <td scope="col"> {{ item.submission }} </td>
                <td scope="col"> {{ item.starting_date }} </td>
                <td scope="col"> {{ item.closing_date }} </td>
                <td scope="col">
                    <a :href="item.link" target="_blank"> View </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </template>
</tbody>
```

To make Vue/eslint stop warning about the missing `key` directive, you could add the following to the `v-for`s:

```
<template v-for="(values, i) in objects">
    <template v-for="(value, j) in values">
        <tr v-for="(item, k) in value" :key="`${i}.${j}.${k}`">
```